# Catching NoneType bugs using isinstance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below code but `not isinstance()` isn't working as expected.

```
<ipython-input-94-009e9fb4f54a> in extract(self, row)
     34             event_payload_json = json.loads(row.event_payload)
     35             #print(event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work'])
---> 36             if not isinstance(event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work'], type(None)):
     37                 if "test_statement" not in event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work']:
     38                     decoded_str = base64.b64decode(<>)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

My intention is exactly to not decode if `event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work']` not NoneType, however it's not working as expected. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems like `event_payload_json['payload']['info']` returns `None` so you try to do `None['work']` which causes the error, no?

Comment: That error means that either 'payload' or 'info' is `None` (serialized as "null'" in JSON), so you never made it as far as the type check. But I don't understand your requirement. You want to not decode if its not NoneType... meaning that you _do_ want to decode if it _is_ NoneType, but that doesn't make sense. I think you need to include a try/except to handle the NoneType.

Answer (score 2):

In Python None is a singleton so can just do:

```
if event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work'] is not None:
```

Also if `event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work']` only takes truthy values then it would be enough to check it like this

```
if event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work']:
```

Comment: OP's `isinstance` works, although this is a better way to do it. OP's actual error is because there is a `None` in either 'payload' or 'info'. To fully fix the problem, there also needs to be a try/except to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you tried to subscript `None`, so either `event_payload_json['payload']` or `event_payload_json['payload']['info']` is `None`. The easiest way to handle that error is to put the statement in a try/except block and catch the `TypeError`. It turns out that attempting to see if a string is in `None` is also a `TypeError`, so you can handle all of your cases all at once.

```
event_payload_json = json.loads(row.event_payload)
#print(event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work'])
try:
    work = event_payload_json['payload']['info']['work']
    if "test_statement" not in work:
        decoded_str = base64.b64decode(work)
except TypeError:
    pass
```